# UWP Xaml Relative Panel, Stretch and Other Element

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I create UWP Application and using RelativePanel.
I use relative panel.alignwithright, top, left, bottom panel for stretch width to listview.
But after add other element (ex. Stackpanel) to right of listview, other panel do not view in page.
So i remove relativePanel.AlignWithRight, in this case can not width stretch in listview.

What can i do?

[image: I want this shape to come out.]

[image: Now RelativePanel]

Code:

```
<RelativePanel x:Name="Information" Grid.Row="1">
            <ListView x:Name="MyList"
                      RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"
                      RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True"
                      RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                      RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <userControl:SpendListItem_Template Tapped="SpendListItem_Template_Tapped" ></userControl:SpendListItem_Template>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>

                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0,10,10"></Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ListView>

            <StackPanel x:Name="TotalInformation" RelativePanel.RightOf="MyList" Width="100">
                <TextBlock>Test Data</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </RelativePanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure you can't do this in pure XAML by just setting the some of the RelativePanel attached properties but you could handle the SizeChanged event of RelativePanel and set the width of the ListView programmatically. It's a one liner:

```
private void Information_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
     MyList.Width = Information.ActualWidth - TotalInformation.ActualWidth;
}
```

---

```
<RelativePanel x:Name="Information" Grid.Row="1" SizeChanged="Information_SizeChanged">
        <ListView x:Name="MyList">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <userControl:SpendListItem_Template Tapped="SpendListItem_Template_Tapped" ></userControl:SpendListItem_Template>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0,10,10"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>

        <StackPanel x:Name="TotalInformation" RelativePanel.RightOf="MyList" Width="100">
            <TextBlock>Test Data</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
 </RelativePanel>
```